# Executing curl command in Java and getting response as String

Tags: java, curl, runtime

I am trying to execute a curl command and get a part of the response as a string.
The command that I am trying to execute is as follows

```bash
curl -X POST "https://kakaoapi.aligo.in/akv10/token/create/30/s/" \
    --data-urlencode "apikey=xxxxx" \
    --data-urlencode "userid=xxxxx"
```

The response that I get when I execute this in the terminal is as follows

```bash
{"code":0,"message":"\uc815\uc0c1\uc801\uc73c\ub85c \uc0dd\uc131\ud558\uc600\uc2b5\ub2c8\ub2e4.","token":"tokenvalue","urlencode":"urlencoded"}%
```

The java code that I am trying to execute to get this result is something like this

```java
String command =
                "curl -X POST \"https://kakaoapi.aligo.in/akv10/token/create/30/s/\" \\\n" +
                        "\t--data-urlencode \"apikey=xxxxx\" \\\n" +
                        "\t--data-urlencode \"userid=xxxxx\"";
        Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        String result = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()))
                .lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        log.info(result);
```

I am currently getting a null value in the log.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a better way of doing this.

I have tried doing this by creating a httpclient and sending a post request, and I did get a response but the authentication failed for some reason.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should try using the HttpPost class

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for your feedback! I have tried making a request via HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); and then creating a new HttpPost. I did get a response but it failed for some reason, so I was trying a curl command as an alternative.

Comment: Maybe curl is not in your path? or some other error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A better way of doing this is by using Unirest library (http://kong.github.io/unirest-java):

```
Unirest.setTimeouts(0, 0);
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://kakaoapi.aligo.in/akv10/token/create/30/s/?apikey=xxxxx&userid=xxxxx")
  .asString();
```

The first step is to install it's maven / gradle dependency and then try the code above.